# osCommerce - how to forbid zip codes for customers

Tags: oscommerce

so I´m sitting at a friend´s, which osCommerce online store is conifgured as such: only certain zip-codes for customers are allowed. I need to add more zip codes, but I can´t find where they´re stored.

Are they in a database or in a csv file, I´ve clicked thru that whole thing now, can´t find anything. I also tried shopname/phpmyadmin.php. nobody can help me here and google can´t either.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Out of Box osCommerce 2.x does not have a feature that restricts zip code selection while customer is creating an account.

Its probably some extension or customization done on cart you are working on.

To make things simple I recommend you to download code and search for zip codes that are being displayed this will land you to code and some hints.

The other option is to download complete data base and check for zip codes that are allowed.
This will in turn give you some idea about data base schema related to this additional module that is limiting zip codes.

other option is to check create_account.php

As this is not a standard feature so cant give a solution with some code.